# Optimizing Selection of the Optimal Qubit in a 30-Qubit Quantum Circuit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, measurement, quantum-circuit

I am working with a quantum circuit consisting of 30 qubits, and for each qubit, I have allocated a dedicated classical register to record individual measurement results. When I execute this circuit and perform these measurements, I obtain a sequence of 30 bits as output. My primary objective is to determine the probabilities associated with each measurement, which essentially involves calculating the frequency of the state 1 for each qubit.

After obtaining these probabilities, my intention is to compare them to identify the qubit with the highest probability of being in the state 1. Once this qubit is identified, I want to keep it in the state 1, while setting the other qubits to the state 0.

Could you guide me on how to accomplish this task efficiently and accurately within the context of a 30-qubit quantum circuit?